# How to Remove SIP or Plus Prefixes from Incoming Calls on FreePBX?

Tags: freepbx

How can I remove the "sip:+" (sip plus) prefix from incoming numbers?  The number is being cached on my phone, and is an illogical format, so I cannot call that number back.

Answer (score 2):

There are two steps needed to fully remove the "sip:+" prefix...

### Removing the Plus Prefix

FreePBX includes a "context" which strips all but the final 10 digits from the CID string.  There are several other threads out there, which say to create a custom context, but this is not necessary.  On your inbound route, if you change this...

```
context=from-trunk
```

... to this ...

```
context=from-pstn-e164-us
```

... incoming numbers will be the 10-digit format, which generally works fine in the US.

### Removing the SIP Prefix

At least in the Polycom world, the SIP prefix is used in conjunction with URL Dialing.  Disabling this feature will cause the "sip:" prefix to not be transmitted to the phone.  Here's how it's done for Polycom units...

1. Select Settings > Endpoint Manager
2. In the right nav, select "Base File Edit" (under "Advanced")
3. Select the template to edit
4. Click the "MAC-Features.cfg" button
5. Search for the "feature.urlDialing" entry with a "1" value
6. Change the "1" to "0" (to disable it)
7. Save your changes
8. Rebuild the config for your phones
9. Reboot your phones

A few notes on this...

- There may be a better way.  This is how I did it.
- In item #5, if you only search for "urlDialing" (and not "feature.urlDialing"), you should find 2 hits for "urlDialing".  The first has a value of "PARENT".  I would not change this.  Search for the next instance, or for the fully qualified "feature.urlDialing", and you'll find the 1 or 0.